# Why are only these 11 countries eligible for Global Entry?

Tags: usa, global-entry

As of November 2018, the [Global Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Entry) program in the USA is open just to USA citizens, USA permanent residents, and to citizens of 11 other countries:

- Citizens of Argentina
- Citizens of India
- Citizens of Colombia
- Citizens of United Kingdom
- Citizens of Germany
- Citizens of Panama
- Citizens of Singapore
- Citizens of South Korea
- Citizens of Switzerland
- Citizens of Taiwan
- Mexican nationals

What’s so special about these 11? I can understand why Canada is missing (you’re supposed to use NEXUS) but why is South Korea there but not Japan? Why Argentina and not Australia? Why the UK but not New Zealand?

The absence of two of the [Five Eyes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) is particularly interesting given that those countries are supposed to be America’s closest allies (well, up to Feb 2017).

**What is the criteria by which the Global Entry eligible  foreign nations are chosen?**

Comment: Note that a pilot program for Japanese citizens to enroll in Global Entry was [launched last fall.](http://bigislandnow.com/2017/09/07/hirono-announces-global-entry-pilot-program-for-japanese-travelers/)

Comment: @michaelseifert indeed there's a smart-entry program in Japan that has started recently, although it is still quite hard to register.

Comment: For explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Entry

Comment: Given current US politics, I am also confused why Mexico is on the list ...

Comment: Global entry to where?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen A person using Global Entry is likely not an illegal alien, but a lawfully admitted one. Makes a difference.

Comment: For Canadians, NEXUS is half the price and better (it works for entering Canada, and includes SENTRI benefits if you get your vehicle inspected).  The only downside is the need to get interviewed in Canada (or at one of the centres near the Canadian border), which could be a pain for Canadian expatriates far from the Canadian border who also rarely go to Canada.  Otherwise, it's a no-brainer to take NEXUS over Global Entry, even if travel to Canada isn't contemplated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These countries have reciprocal smart-entry agreements with the US. In these countries, US citizens can use, after registration, electronic gates when arriving and leaving. And citizens of these countries can do the same in the US.

Comment: This does not explain why Australia is missing.  Australia has allowed US citizens with Global Entry to use their SmartGates for many years, and has allowed ALL US citizens to use them for over 2 years.  Whilst this may be part of the answer, it is clearly not the full answer...

Comment: @Doc I guess many other stuff dors not make sense... including this one.

Comment: @Doc: There seems to be a difference between allowing someone to do some thing and having a mutual agreement signed by officials.

Comment: Auckland airport has a special lane for American Global Entry members but New Zealand citizens aren't eligible for GE. On the other hand, Switzerland has APC gates that I don't think Americans can use and I haven't noticed India or Argentina (that I've been to recently) doing anything special for arriving Americans either. I don't think reciprocity is strictly necessary, my guess is it is more about the countries involved being willing and able to reliably share information about their own citizen's behaviour at home with the US.

Comment: As Tom noted in a deleted post, you do not need Global Entry to use APC kiosks if you are entering on a visa waiver or a B1/B2/D visa. Global Entry is a trusted traveler program, and should not be conflated with expedited entry systems.